# How to pass Fucntion and Arguments in C++ when '&&' signature is involved?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an `enqueue` function here with the following definition:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
auto ThreadPool::enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args)
```

The 2 function I need to pass both present in `Matrix` class, the first:

```
Matrix tester_gar(Matrix &m)
{
    printf("It came here");
    return m;
}
```

The second:

```
void tester_garbage()
{
    printf("It came here for no argument");
}
```

Here, Matrix is a structure, its definition is not necessary for this issue(can post it if required).I have tried some methods like the following to call the `enqueue` function some ways but they all fail.

```
Matrix a;
pool.enqueue(std::bind(&Matrix::tester_gar,&a),a);
```

OR

```
Matrix a;
pool.enqueue(std::bind(&Matrix::tester_garbage,&a));
```

Normally , either function would have to used as `a.tester_garbage()` or `a.tester_gar(a)`. How do I use them in this scenario ?

Comment: Normally you need to call std::move(x) to convert x to an rvalue-reference (&&)

Comment: @Valentin: except that there is no rvalue reference involved. The parameters to `enqueue()` are deduced, i.e., they are _forwarding references_.

Comment: @DietmarKühl ahh you're right of course. I hate this syntax:)

Comment: What do you mean "they all fail"? Are there error messages? Create a [mcve]. [What you showed have a clear error message](https://godbolt.org/g/FubPKB)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement isn't quite precise. However, you certainly should either properly `bind()` the functions or, probably preferably, omit the `bind()` entirely:

```
pool.enqueue(&Matrix::tester_gar, &a, a);
pool.enqueue(&Matrix::tester_garbage, &a);
```

These assume that the `enqueue()` figures out that the first parameter is a member function pointer rather than a callable. If it complains you may need to pass `std::mem_fn(&Matrix::test_gar)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what `enqueue()` expects, but from the looks of it it expects one callable, and then the arguments of the callable. If that's true, then you should be able to use lambdas:

```
Matrix a;
Matrix m;
pool.enqueue([a](Matrix &m){ a.tester_gar(m); }, m);
pool.enqueue([a](){ a.tester_garbage(); });
```

Or, more readable:

```
Matrix a;
Matrix m;

auto func1 = [a](Matrix &m)
{
    a.tester_gar(m);
};

auto func2 = [a]()
{
    a.tester_garbage();
};

pool.enqueue(func1, m);
pool.enqueue(func2);
```

`tester_gar()` and `tester_garbage()` are going to be called on a *copy* of `a`. If you want to call them on the original `a`, then capture `a` by reference, by using `[&a]` instead of `[a]`. Pay attention to the lifetime of `a` if you capture by reference.